# AdSense is not displayed. In console there is ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error for integrator.js script

Tags: javascript, adsense, banner

I have an issue that AdSense banners sometimes are not shown on our site. In console I see error
GET https://adservice.google.by/adsid/integrator.js?domain=my_domain::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Can you please advise why this error happens and how it can be fixed. Or if there are any other reasons why AdSense banners can be not shown from time to time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find solution?